# Get categories trail on catalog page

Tags: category

For example I'm on boots catalog page: `Shoes > Womens > Boots`

If I add this code:

```
$category = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/navigation')->getCurrentCategory();
```

It'll return only `Boots` category. How can I get full trail programatically starting from `Shoes`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looping through the result of

```
Mage::helper('catalog')->getBreadcrumbPath()
```